# Is it allowed to use the script tag inside the paragraph tag? - HTML5

Tags: html

Is it allowed to use the `script tag` inside the `paragraph tag`? - HTML5

Comment: Actually this is one of the canonical examples of [injection vulnerability](https://owasp.org/Top10/A03_2021-Injection/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can. It's not recommended to use inline scripts whenever it can be avoided, but it's valid syntactically.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      <script>
      </script>
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Check in http://validator.w3.org/check , override `DOCTYPE` to `HTML5`